# Correct __sync_bool_compare_and_swap usage?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, thread-safety

I'm trying to compare locking and lock free data structures, and I was hoping to use the __sync_bool_compare_and_swap method [described here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).

Basically the only two operations I need to support are increasing and decreasing the current value of an int safely, and this is how I've implemented it so far:

```
int withdraw(CAccount* account, int amount) {
    int expected;
    int new;
    int* pCurrent = &(account->balance);
    do {
        expected = *pCurrent;
        new = expected - amount;
    } while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(pCurrent, expected, new));
    return amount;
}
```

I can't find any examples of this method being used like this elsewhere, so I'm not entirely sure if this is how it's mean to be used, so please correct me if this isn't right!

Also is this one of the situations where the *val* version of the method would be preferred over *bool*?

Thanks!

Comment: if two threads called `withdraw` at the same time, would this implementation properly calculate the new balance in `new`?

Comment: @bruceg my understanding is that the memory barrier that is used when __sync_bool_compare_and_swap runs will ensure that the compare and write will occur atomically, so yes.

Comment: Let's say that two threads come in to withdraw `amount = 10`, and the current account balance is 100, and both threads hit the do-while loop at the same time. Then expected is 100 for both threads the first time through the loop.  One thread wins, and the atomic operation sets the account balance down to 90, and the other thread loses, and has to iterate a second time, before decrementing the account balance.  So, if there are three threads, then you'd have another round of this competition. So, this implementation will have to iterate n-squared times through the loop for n threads.

Comment: Thus, I don't see how the `val` version would improve it.

Comment: @bruceg I'm aware of the difference between the val and bool verisons, I was hoping someone would tell me if my code was thread safe, and you've done just that!